# How to use url() to get domain routes laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain, laravel-5

consider the following example:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'something.example.local'], function() {
    Route::get('scripts', 'SomethingController@scripts');
});
```

Now lets assume you are are on `something.example.local/scripts` and you hover over a link as such: `<a href="{{ url(/scripts) }}">hello world</a>` you will see `something.example.local/scripts`. great.

No go to `example.local` and do the same thing: `example.local/scripts` .... Thats wrong. It should say: `something.example.local/scripts`.

**How do you use laravel helper methods to get the appropriate and complete url, domain and all?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think you should name your route.

Here:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'something.example.local'], function() {
    Route::get('scripts', ['as' => 'route.name', 'uses' => 'SomethingController@scripts']);
});
```

And in your `a` tag:

```
<a href="{{ route('route.name') }}">hello world</a>
```

Done!